# Easy way to create a constant size queue in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, queue

Is there any way to use a FIFO queue in MATLAB? It seems that it does not have this data structure directly.

I have a loop and want to have a queue of 100 numbers during the process of loop. Then in every iteration, I want to add a new number to queue and eliminate the oldest number from queue. I need the average of these 100 numbers in every loop. I thought that using queue is the best way for this task.

Comment: There is no built in way, but you can write a simple class that implement just that

Comment: For fundamental types, a simple array makes an effective queue. What data do you need to store in the queue? How are you going to use it? Have you written any code or an outline of your algorithm?

Comment: For a fixed queue length, search for array implementations of a circular queue.

Comment: How are the numbers generated? Is this a signal or image that you have in memory all at once? Or are numbers continually coming into the system and you are not able to store all of them? -- You want to compute the running mean, there are well-known ways of doing this that are very efficient, I recommend that you don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @CrisLuengo . All of the numbers are not available in the first of the execution. In every iteration, just one of them will be generated. so I have to allow the loop to iterate for 100 times to and just store the numbers and after that, I have a mean of first 100 numbers. then in every loop, I will add a new number to the sequence and eliminate the oldest number to update the mean. The implementation is not difficult, but I search for the easiest solution for this problem in MATLAB.

Comment: I think the solution that @Mefitico has been written is a rational solution. But I thought that MATLAB has better data structures for tasks like this.

Comment: I would use a fixed-size array for the queue, and replace one value at the time. Note that you can also keep a running sum of the elements in  your queue, every loop iteration you subtract from this sum the element you remove from the queue, and add the new element.

Comment: @CrisLuengo You are right. Thank you very much

Comment: The concept is called “circular buffer”. FYI: There are 3 reopen votes on the question, it takes a little time sometimes to reopen a question, but I believe it’s answerable now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a vector of structs and use it as a queue. It is not efficient, but should be easy and solve your problem.

Say you have:

```
obj1 = struct('field1', 1, 'field2', 2);
obj2 = struct('field1', 2, 'field2', 3);
```

Then you can do:

```
queue = [obj1; obj2];
```

The first element can be accessed with `queue(1)`, and the last with `queue(end)`

Then, you can remove the first element by assigning:

```
queue = queue(2:end);
```

Or the last one with:

```
queue = queue(1:end-1);
```

You can also add new elements with:

```
queue(end+1) = new_obj;
```